# jquery .val punctuation?

Tags: jquery

I am using `.val()` to get the value of an input field however when I type in characters like ; it doesn't seem to get the value, is there an issue with punctuation and how can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7zBzy/

Comment: Please post a sample of your code.

Comment: Can you post some example code? Here's an example fiddle in which the value is alerted no matter what characters are entered - http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/hJtNK/

Comment: it's likely more a problem with what you are doing with the val()  after you get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me, here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bpegp/, you have some bug somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

This definitely works regardless of what characters you put in the textbox, there must be a problem somewhere else?

```
<input id="something" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Go" />

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btn').click(function(){
  alert($('#something').val());
 });
});
```